Proportion of variance in a linear regression model with a covaring predictor
Given a model:
\begin{align}Y_{i}=Z_{i}*\beta * X_{i} + Z_{i}\tag{Eq. 1}&\end{align}
I am interested in a closed formula for the proportion of variance explained by the predictor variable $X$, commonly called also coefficient of determination. Note that in this model the variable $Z_{i}$ covary with $X_{i}$, so this is not necessarily a linear regression model with a single predictor.
I know that the proportion of variance (aka coefficient of determination) can be calculated using the following expression:
\begin{align}R^2=\beta^2*\frac{V(X)}{V(Y)}\tag{Eq. 2}&\end{align}
I though in two possible alternatives to achieve my objective:

Divide the response variable $Y_{i}$ by $Z_{i}$, such that:
\begin{align}\frac{Y_{i}}{Z_{i}}=\beta * X_{i} + 1\tag{Eq. 3}&\end{align}
And then use the $Eq. 2$ accordingly.

Consider the expectation of $Z_{i}$ as a constant, such that:
\begin{align}Y_{i}=\beta' * X_{i} + \operatorname{E}(Z)\tag{Eq. 4}&\end{align}
where $\beta'=\operatorname{E}(Z)*\beta$. Then use $Eq. 2$ accordingly.


When I compare the slope estimated by linear regression on some simulation data (here not shown) with the expected slope (calculated using prior information on the simulated data), for both Eq. 3 and Eq. 4, I do get very accurate results.
The same is not true for $R^2$ calculated in the model at Eq. 4.
I presume that applying the expression of $R^2$ i Eq. 2 (accurate for a single predictor linear regression) might not be as good for the model in Eq. 1.
